# Parametric second derivative

Tags: calculus

I am working on a matamatics problem where I have the following equations and need to calculate the second derivative.

I have the two equations:
$$
Y=a^3-\frac53t^2\\
X = a^{1/2}
$$
I worked out the first derivative to be:
$$
2a^{3/2}(3a-5)
$$
And the second derivative as 
$$
9a^{1.5}-15a^{0.5}
$$
However the question says to state it in the form:
$$
ca^2 +ba
$$
What mistake have I made?

Comment: I have transcribed your equations to conform with our [math formatting system](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please make sure that I have not made any mistakes.

Comment: Are you sure that it is $t^2$ in the first equation ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the equations are exactly as written.